# Using multiple VB Mid functions on a parameter in SSRS

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

Below is an expression I am using to pull out the forename from a user ID

i.e. `"text\[forename] [Surname]"`

at the moment this expression is suitable if " " is between the forename and surname. However, what i have noticed is that " " can be replaced by "." or "/" or "_" for example.

The trouble I am having is including multiple "Mid" functions to include all these options. I have attempted using "Or", "Switch" and a number of other operators with no effect.

I am not using a dataset, rather a parameter within the report i.e. when a user logs onto the report, their UserID is taken as the paramter.

Am I missing something obvious or have i missed the mark completely?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
= "Hi " + Mid(Parameters!User.Value, InStr(Parameters!User.Value,"\")+1, (InStr(Parameters!User.Value, " ") - InStr(Parameters!User.Value, "\") - 1)) + "," &
chr(10) & chr(13) &
chr(10) & chr(13) &
"You have access to the Teams listed below. Only data from these teams will be shown in any analysis. Please click above to continue to the Dashboards"
```

Comment: Don't put this on one line... You might want to look at regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is definitely the way to go for something like this.  Here's an example of how you could pull out the forename with regex:

```
Dim input As String = Parameters!User.Value
Dim pattern As String = "(?<=\\)[^ ./_]+"
Dim forename As String = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Value
Dim output As String = $"Hi {forename},

You have access to the Teams listed below. Only data from these teams will be shown in any analysis. Please click above to continue to the Dashboards"
```

VB.NET now allows multi-line string literals, so there's no need to use `Chr(10) & Chr(13)`.  Even if you don't use a multi-line literal, it would be better to use `Environment.NewLine` or `vbCrLf` depending on your needs.  The `$` before the string literal makes it an interpolated string, which means that you can insert variable values in `{}` brackets in the middle of the string.  If you don't want to use that, you could just concatenate as you were doing before:

```
Dim output As String = "Hi " & forename & 
    Environment.NewLine & 
    Environment.NewLine &
    "You have access to the Teams listed below. Only data from these teams will be shown in any analysis. Please click above to continue to the Dashboards"
```

Regex is a powerful tool for searching, parsing, and transforming strings.  If you're going to be doing a lot of work with data, it will be well worth your effort to learn it.

If you don't want to use regex, I would recommend using `String.Split`, since that method allows you can pass it any number of delimiters.  For instance, you could do something like this:

```
Dim input As String = Parameters!User.Value
Dim parts() As String = input.Split("\"c, " "c, "."c, "/"c, "_"c)
Dim forename As String = If(parts.Length >= 2, parts(1), Nothing)
```

Comment: In terms of using an 'IIF()' statement, is this also a possible route to go? Or that method too inefficient?

Comment: Oops.  Thanks @NicoButler for bringing this back to my attention.  You caused me to re-read the original question which made me realize that I had misread the problem.  I thought that it was the slash that might be other characters, but it was the space.  I updated the regex pattern so that it will work properly.  I also added an example of how it could be done without regex.  `IIF` (or better yet, just the newer ternary `If` operator in VB.NET) would certainly work, but I fear that it would get a bit long and unreadable.  It would also be harder to add more flexibility in the future.